# Tomcat 8.5 HTTP/2 connector not supporting GZIP compression

Tags: gzip, http2, tomcat8.5

It looks like tomcat 8.5 H2 protocol does not support GZIP compression.
Can anyone confirm or give advise on how to enable it?

The following does not work:

```
<Connector 
  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" 
  port="8443" 
  connectionTimeout="20000" 
  executor="main" 
  SSLEnabled="true" 
  scheme="https" 
  secure="true" 
  URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
  maxHttpHeaderSize="10240"
  compression="force" 
  SSLCertificateKeyFile="${tomcat.conf.dir}/key.pem"
  SSLCertificateFile="${tomcat.conf.dir}/cert.pem" 
  SSLPassword="changeit">
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />                   
</Connector>
```

Comment: Hi Patrizio, Can you try adding useSendfile="false" in the connector?

Comment: "bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60276 Fixed in: - trunk for 9.0.3 onwards - 8.5.x for 8.5.25 onwards" but i have the same problem :¬|.